# Binding window height in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class VirtualKeyboard which extends the Window class.
I have another class - EnglishVirtualKeyboard, which extends from the VirtualKeyboard class.

This is what I have in EnglishVirtualKeyboard.xaml:

```
<vk:VirtualKeyboard x:Class="Hurst.VirtualKeyboard.EnglishVirtualKeyboard"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:vk="clr-namespace:Hurst.VirtualKeyboard"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Hurst.VirtualKeyboard.ViewModels"
DataContext="{DynamicResource keyboardViewModel}"
Height="{Binding KeyboardWindowHeight}" Width="1280" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="710" 
x:Name="VK">

<vk:VirtualKeyboard.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="keyboardViewModel" ObjectType="{x:Type vm:KeyboardViewModel}" />
</vk:VirtualKeyboard.Resources>
```

KeyboardWindowHeight is a property in the KeyboardViewModel class.

When I click on one button from the keyboard, I want the height of the window to change. Here's my code:

```
if (buttonPressed)
{
    KeyboardWindowHeight = 400;
}
else
{
    KeyboardWindowHeight = 485;
}
Notify("KeyboardWindowHeight");
```

And here's the Notify method:

```
public void Notify([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        this.VerifyProperty(propertyName);

        // Make a copy of the PropertyChanged event first, before testing it for null,
        // because another thread might change it between the two statements.
        var copyOfPropertyChangedEvent = PropertyChanged;

        if (copyOfPropertyChangedEvent != null)
        {
            // Get the cached event-arg.
            var args = GetPropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            copyOfPropertyChangedEvent(this, args);
        }

        this.AfterPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

This code is in the ViewModel class, from which KeyboardViewModel extends and which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

My problem is this:

When I click on the button, KeyboardWindowHeight gets changed, Notify is called, but the window height remains the same. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to bind KeyboardWindowHeight property to MinHeight and MaxHeight, as well as Height?

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool Button_clicked
    {
        get
        {
            return _button_clicked;
        }
        set
        {
            _button_clicked = value;
            if (value)
                Win_height = 500;
            else
                Win_height = 300;
            onPropertyChanged("Button_clicked");
        }
    }
```

binding *Win_height* property to the *Height* property in xaml should work